# Discord.js V14 Shards Command Not Working

Tags: javascript, discord.js, sharding

It is not working with this code please can anybody help me

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "shards",
  category: "Owner",
  description: "Provides information about shard pings and guild counts",
  cooldown: 1,
  memberpermissions: [],
  requiredroles: [],
  alloweduserids: [],
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    try {
      const shardManager = client.ws.shards;
      const shardPings = shardManager.map((shard) => shard.ping);
      const averagePing = shardPings.length ? shardPings.reduce((prev, val) => prev + val, 0) / shardPings.length : Infinity;

      const guildCounts = await client.shard.fetchClientValues("guilds.cache.size");
      const shardGuildCounts = guildCounts.length ? guildCounts.map((count, shardID) => `:Ping: Shard ${shardID}: ${shardPings[shardID]} ms | ${count} guilds`).join("\n") : "Guild Counts Unavailable";

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Shard Information")
        .setColor("#fffb00")
        .addFields(
          { name: "Average Ping", value: `:Ping: ${averagePing.toFixed(2)} ms` },
          { name: "Shards Info", value: shardGuildCounts }
        );

      await interaction.reply({
        embeds: [embed.build()],
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(String(e.stack).bgRed);
    }
  },
};
```

I was expecting it would look good in a embed and that it’s not giving some errors but every time it’s giving me a error why

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.